# There is an error with sklearn (LogisticRegression model selection)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn import datasets
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


    Dt = pd.read_csv("D:\wisc_bc_data.csv")
    '''
    print(Dt.shape)     
    print(Dt.head())
    '''
     def changer(x):
         if x == 'B':
            return 0
         else:
            return 1
     Dt['diagnosis'] = Dt['diagnosis'].map(lambda x: changer(x))
     features = Dt[2:12]
     Diagnosis = Dt['diagnosis']
     train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, Diagnosis) 'this line emits error code'

     '''
     this is my code and i used dataset from here: https://gomguard.tistory.com/52
     '''
```

### I'd like to split data for logistic regression. However, There was an error code like this:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 train_features, test_features, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(features, Diagnosis)

D:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
2116         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
2117
-> 2118     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
2119
2120     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

D:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
246     """
247     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 248     check_consistent_length(*result)
249     return result
250

D:\python\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
210     if len(uniques) > 1:
211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
213
214

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10, 569]
​ how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `features = Dt[2:12]` results in your error.
Your attempt is to slice features, but the python interprets the code to slice records.
So, change the code as `Dt.iloc[:, 2:12`].